# ARM Cortex M3 (ATSAM3N4B) IACCVIOL Hard Fault

Tags: arm, cortex-m3, cortex-m

The ATSAM3N4B is an ARM Cortex M3 microcontroller from Atmel. I wanted to ask if anyone can help clarify the IACCVIOL Hard Fault processing.

What I want is the infringing instruction address which the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc11011.pdf) explains in 10.21.11.1 (pg 182) as:

> **IACCVIOL**
>
> Instruction access violation flag:
>
> 0 = no instruction access violation fault
>
> 1 = the processor attempted an instruction fetch from a location that does not permit execution.
>
> When this bit is 1, the PC value *stacked* for the exception return points to the faulting instruction. The processor has not written a fault address to the MMAR.

What I want help with is the *stacked for the exception return*? I don't understand what this refers to.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, it seems I did not utilize google enough.

Section 10.6.7 of the given [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc11011.pdf) also described on [this ARM information center page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html) describes the Exception entry and return process.

So the answer to my question is that faulting instruction address resides on the stack at an offset of `+0x18` after entering the exception handler.